# Extracting Unstructured Addresses and email ids as variables from scraped text - Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, bots

I am a novice in python, so please pardon me if it seems to be a simple problem. The Below code successfully scrapes a webpage. Is there a way to extract Addresses, email ids & contact numbers from this text and put it in a dataframe. I have searched two ways to do so :-

- REGEX - But it may not work as i have many websites to scrape and the
  addresses may not be always structured in a regular pattern.
- Pyap - It caters only to US & Canadian Addresses.

Is there a way apart from the above two to fetch the required details :-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = input("ENTER WEBPAGE") # for example, i am using this webpage as of now "[https://glg.it/contact-us/][1] "

response = requests.get(url)

details = response.text

scraped_details = BeautifulSoup(details, "html.parser")
pretty1 = scraped_details.prettify()
print(pretty1)
```

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

Regex can be used by modifying expression which matches most of the address format>br>

```
import re

txt = ...
regexp = "[0-9]{1,3} .+, .+, [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}"
address = re.findall(regexp, txt)

# address = ['44 West 22nd Street, New York, NY 12345']
```

Explanation:

`[0-9]{1,3}`: 1 to 3 digits, the address number

`(space)`: a space between the number and the street name

`.+`: street name, any character for any number of occurrences

`,`: a comma and a space before the city

`.+`: city, any character for any number of occurrences

`,`: a comma and a space before the state

`[A-Z]{2}`: exactly 2 uppercase chars from A to Z

`[0-9]{5}`: 5 digits

`re.findall(expr, string)` will return an array with all the occurrences found.

Comment: It doesn't work. For instance, it gives empty list if i go about scraping this link - https://portcullis.co/en/contact-us/
Any other way ?